# two-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-comprehension

There is a task on CodeFights involving building a two-dimensional array:

> A spiral matrix is a square matrix of size n × n. It contains all the
>   integers in range from 1 to n * n so that number 1 is written in the
>   bottom right corner, and all other numbers are written in increasing
>   order spirally in the counterclockwise direction.
>
> Given the size of the matrix n, your task is to create a spiral
>   matrix.

One is supposed to fill only one gap denoted by ... in the following code:

```
def createSpiralMatrix(n):
    dirs = [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]
    curDir = 0
    curPos = (n - 1, n - 1)
    res = ...

    for i in range(1, n * n + 1):
        res[curPos[0]][curPos[1]] = i
        nextPos = curPos[0] + dirs[curDir][0], curPos[1] + dirs[curDir][1]
        if not (0 <= nextPos[0] < n and
                0 <= nextPos[1] < n and
                res[nextPos[0]][nextPos[1]] == 0):
            curDir = (curDir + 1) % 4
            nextPos = curPos[0] + dirs[curDir][0], curPos[1] + dirs[curDir][1]
        curPos = nextPos

    return res
```

When I fill in the following code, all tests are passed:

```
res = [[0 for item in range(n)] for sublist in range(n)]
```

However, if I slightly change it to:

```
res = [[None for item in range(n)] for sublist in range(n)]
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Execution error on test 1: Something went wrong when executing the solution - program stopped unexpectedly with an error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  file.py3 on line ?, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _runiuljw(testInputs[i])
  file.py3 on line ?, in _runiuljw
    return createSpiralMatrix(*_fArgs_jlosndfelxsr)
  file.py3 on line 8, in createSpiralMatrix
    res[curPos[0]][curPos[1]] = i
IndexError: list index out of range
```

> Test 1 Input: n: 3 Output: Empty Expected Output: [[5,4,3],   [6,9,2],
>   [7,8,1]] Console Output: Empty

The same result (with the error message) is with the following code:

```
res = [list(range(n)) for sublist in range(n)]
```

All three options build arrays of the same size:

```
n = 3

res = [[0 for item in range(n)] for sublist in range(n)]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

res = [[None for item in range(n)] for sublist in range(n)]

[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]

res = [list(range(n)) for sublist in range(n)]

[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work with `None`, then you simply have to change the third condition of your `if not ...` statement to agree with how you initialized `res`. Otherwise, `nextPos` will incorrectly become out of the range of your 2D array.

```
def createSpiralMatrix(n):
    dirs = [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]
    curDir = 0
    curPos = (n - 1, n - 1)
    res = [[None for item in range(n)] for sublist in range(n)]

    for i in range(1, n * n + 1):
        res[curPos[0]][curPos[1]] = i
        nextPos = curPos[0] + dirs[curDir][0], curPos[1] + dirs[curDir][1]
        if not (0 <= nextPos[0] < n and
                0 <= nextPos[1] < n and
                res[nextPos[0]][nextPos[1]] is None): # Changed this line
            curDir = (curDir + 1) % 4
            nextPos = curPos[0] + dirs[curDir][0], curPos[1] + dirs[curDir][1]
        curPos = nextPos

    return res
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why the difference?

Comment: In your original code, the third condition was `res[nextPos[0]][nextPos[1]] == 0`. But you initialized `res` to all `None` entries. So, why would you expect that condition to ever be true? If you initialized `res` with `"asdf"`, then that third condition should be `res[nextPos[0]][nextPos[1]] == "asdf"`. The problem was never that your 2D array was the wrong size. The problem was that you initialized it with `None`, then compared it against `0`.